# Post is missing after posting through Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook graph api for posting status on wall with "me/feed".

I get a success response with ID but I don't see the post on my wall
and while I open facebook.com/ID I get "Sorry, this page isn't available".

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the permission for "publish_actions" from access tokens. [Documentation link for Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#permissions) Later You may hav to use a Publish action. [Documentation link for Publishing Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0)

Answer (score 0):

The user was connected with fan page user.